# GET ID after submitting form

Tags: php

Im trying to get the ID when I insert a SQL, I've tried to get the last. I've tried to echo out the ID in the hidden html form but without any success

As you see I've $sql that inserts INTO log_create, but from that I need to receive the ID which is created, it need to be echoed

```
$id = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['id']));
$name2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $name);
$game = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['game']));
$info = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['info'])); 
$mobname = $db->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['mobname']));
$sql = "INSERT INTO log_create(`id`, `name`, name2, game, monster, info)VALUES('$id', '$name', '$name2', '$game', '$mobname', '$info')";
if($result=$db->query($sql))
{
    $log = $db->query("SELECT itemname FROM `log_mitem` WHERE mobname = '".$mobname."' AND game = '".$game."'") or die($db->error);
    if($log1 = $log->fetch_object());
    {
        while($loco = $log->fetch_object())
    {
        $item = "$loco->itemname";
        $logss = "INSERT INTO log_drops(`item`, `mobname`, `game`, `log_id`, `log_name`)VALUES('$item', '$mobname', '$game', '$id', '$name')";
        if($result1 = $db->query($logss)); 
    }
    }
echo '<p>';
echo 'Your droplog has been created! Check your droplog category to start hunting!';
echo '</p>';
} else { echo 'Something went wrong!';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)may help you, maybe?

Good luck! :-)

EDIT: My bad, I should have said what was that, instead of linking directly.

It's the mysqli::$insert_id variable.

It stores the last ID created by the last used "INSERT" sentence.

```
...
if($result=$db->query($sql))
{    
echo "New ID: "+$db->insert_id+"<br />";
...
```

Or wherever you want to use it.

Make sure to store it before inserting anything else, or it'll be replaced.

Comment: Don't answer with just a link. Provide a code example. [answer]

Comment: My bad, I noticed it just after posting. Still getting used to the site, sorry.

Comment: I got this now: ` if($result=$db->query($sql))
 {
  $id = "$result->insert_id";`
And I'm getting this error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: The insert_id is a property of the database link, not of the result. Do "$db->insert_id" instead. Plus, the "" are not necessary. It would be:
   $id=$db->insert_id;

Comment: Thank you guys! Excuse me for this simple question I had certain problems but it's working thank you!